# How do I trigger Excel to launch after creating an xlsx?

Tags: python, pandas, windows

I've converted my df to an excel file (.xlsx) but I wish there were method where I can "launch" the created excel file IN excel (not load xlsx as DF, but trigger MS office to open)

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
import os   
excel_file = "full_path_to_your_file"
os.system(excel_file)
```

for relative path:

```
excel_file = os.path.abspath('relative_path_to_file')
os.system(excel_file)
```